# Comparing two Images using image processing in Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a project that is to develop an android app that will detect the percentage of similarities of two pictures.
I am new to both android and image processing.
These two picture might not be taken in same conditions like there will be brightness difference for example.
What is the best way to do this?
take these two images for example
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8IXI.jpg) and [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAvbq.jpg).
I know these might not be the best example but the point is that they might not be very similar. One is taken from good camera and other is taken from cell phone's camera.
Your precious suggestions would oblige me a lot.

Comment: You need to ask yourself what you actually want to compare?  Do you want to compare how similar two images are digitally?  Do you want to compare the physical elements of the images?  There are many things you can compare.  Sounds like you need to clarify this to yourself first.

Comment: Removed the MATLAB tag as your inquiry isn't related to the language.

Comment: Check out these two answers: * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853989/opencv-image-comparison-in-android
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595935/comparing-pictures-using-android-opencv Use histogram comparison or feature matching

Comment: This is the problem, my boss gave me this project and told me to do it without asking for help from me, so what should I do if I dont have enough knowledge!

Comment: All I want to do is to apply algorithm that will change dimensions like brightness to check if Change in dimension gets better results..
What to do in this case? @LukePark